# Uncentered ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I dunno why I am getting my plot shifted to the right:

```
x = data.frame(vals = round(runif(500, min=1, max=4)))

ggplot(x, aes(x=vals)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)),
        binwidth=0.5, origin=-0.25) +
    scale_x_discrete(name='numbers',
        limits=c(1,2,3,4)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name='%', labels=percent,
        limits=c(0,0.5))
```

I tried with real data and the above simulation. I thought that some weird values are hidden in my data, but it is clean frame.

Please, help!

Comment: I think maybe you maybe wanted `aes(x = factor(vals))`, if you really want `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: `labels=percent` also causes problems for reasons I don't totally understand. In any case when I run this without `scale_y_continuous` the plot I get doesn't seem to be shifted to the right in any meaningful sense. Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: @joran gave just the right advice! Thanks!

Comment: I think you can set origin to 1, it will be centered